# Algorithm for insertion in one-dimensional array, what is happening here?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int arr[5], size, i, pos, elem;

printf("Enter the size of array(less than 100)\n");
scanf("%d",&size);

printf("\nEnter the elements of array one by one\n");

for ( i = 0; i < size; i++)
scanf("%d",&arr[i]);

printf("\nEnter the position of insertion\n");
scanf("%d",&pos);

printf("\nEnter the element\n");
scanf("%d",&elem);

for ( i = size - 1 ; i >= pos - 1; i--)
    arr[i + 1] = arr[i];

arr[pos - 1] = elem;

printf("\nInserted array is\n");

for ( i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    printf("\t%d",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");



return 0;
}
```

Since the array is int arr[5] it shouldn't be possible to insert an element at any index not in range [0,1,2,3,4]. Why am I able to insert at arr[6] and get correct answer still?.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour. You can't expect any particular outcome from running this program.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you from writing beyond the limits of an array, but it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing array out of bound leads to *undefined behvaior*.

You might see it working sometimes and might not work sometimes.(You might end up with a *crash* even)

So just go by the standard and stop accessing array out of bound.
Get rid of the *undefined behavior*

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to memory that you did not allocate.  Eventually, when you hit memory that you do not have write permissions for, you will get a segmentation fault.

C/C++ doesn't do bounds checking for you like other languages such as Java.  It leaves it to the operating system to figure out when you're accessing memory you're not supposed to.